# PHP csv string parsing

Tags: php, string, csv, explode

I have a PHP CSV file that looks like this:

```
'numberOfProducts'  'lastUpdated'
'28'    '2016-09-19 06:55'
```

I tried to do like this:

```
print_r( str_getcsv( $csv, "\n", "\t" ) );
print_r( str_getcsv( $csv, "\t", "\n" ) );
```

It's just a mess.

### Expected result

But my expected result should be something like this:

```
'numberOfProducts' => '28'
'lastUpdated' => '2016-09-19 06:55'
```

Is it possible with [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or is it easier with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

### Result

The is my result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => numberOfProducts
    [1] => lastUpdated
'28'
    [2] => 2016-09-19 06:55
)
```

Not like my expected result.

Comment: **CSV** Stands for COMMA Seperated Values. **You got no commas seperating your values**

Comment: Therefore thats a file. which ___may or may not___ have any formatting!

Comment: try replacing tabs w/ commas and then redoing the thing.

Comment: The `*getcsv` methods should allow you to specify a delimeter of your choice, but you only get one, you don't get two. The third parameter specifies the _enclosure_ character, or how to escape values that contain within them the delimeter as data.

Comment: If you [read the manual to learn how to use `str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str-getcsv) you should see that the second and third arguments are for specifying the `delimiter` and `enclosure`. ***Clearly*** your delimiter here isn't **line feed** character and ***clearly*** your enclosure isn't a **carriage return** character.

Comment: I updated my question with result and why it does not look like the expected result. I changed to a comma, but the result is the same.

Comment: Looks like a .tsv or fixed-width file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*str_getcsv*" only parse one row at a time:

You need to run it for each row:

```
$rows = explode("\n", $csv);
foreach($rows as $row){
    print_r( str_getcsv( $row, "\t", "'") );
}
```

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer, and perhaps works for the OP's specific situation, it is incorrect. It will fail if one of the fields contains a newline.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is quite clear

> `array str_getcsv ( string $input [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]] )`

Your delimiter is neither `\n`, nor `\r` - which both represents line breaks. Your delimiter looks like tab. So try it with

```
print_r( str_getcsv( $csv, "\t", "'"));
```

Comment: Oh, I made a typo. I tried "\t" before. With your code I get 
Array
(
    [0] => numberOfProducts
    [1] => lastUpdated
'28'
    [2] => 2016-09-19 06:55
)
 which is not my expected output, but maybe I can't use this function for that purpose? I also updated my question.